# Numbering theorems within the innermost sectioning environment present at that point in the document?

Tags: numbering, theorems, counters

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

Chapter 1.
...
Theorem 1.1.
...
Section 1.1.
...
Theorem 1.1.1.
...
Subsection 1.1.1.
...
Theorem 1.1.1.1.

Is this even possible? If so, how?
...

Comment: Just to clarify, you want one environment that will automatically detect the sectioning depth?

Comment: That is indeed what I want. (I have several other theorem environments that will be synchronized with the theorem environment's counter.)

Answer (score 7):

Using the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) you can patch the sectional commands (`\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`, ...) to redefine the way the `theorem` counter works. Resetting the `theorem` counter at every sectional unit is obtained via `\@addtoreset`, although this is also possible using the [`chngcntr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr)). Here's a working minimal example that does exactly that:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctann.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% Modify theorem counter to match that of the section unit
\preto{\chapter}{\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thechapter.\arabic{theorem}}}%
\preto{\section}{\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesection.\arabic{theorem}}}%
\preto{\subsection}{\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesubsection.\arabic{theorem}}}%

% Reset the counter at every sectional unit
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{theorem}{chapter}
\@addtoreset{theorem}{section}
\@addtoreset{theorem}{subsection}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{theorem} This is a theorem \end{theorem}
\section{First section}
\begin{theorem} This is a theorem \end{theorem}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{theorem} This is a theorem \end{theorem}
\section{Second section}
\begin{theorem} This is a theorem \end{theorem}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{theorem} This is a theorem \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} This is a theorem \end{theorem}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\begin{theorem} This is a theorem \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: Section-synchronized theorem]

Comment: Trying this gives me a LaTeX error about \thetheorem being undefined when I hit my first \chapter command.

Comment: Did you copy/paste the *entire* minimal example, or just use part of it in your document? If `\thetheorem` is undefined, it could be that you need `\newcounter{theorem}` before `\newtheorem{..}{..}`. Try that as a quick-fix attempt. Otherwise, report back with more information.

Comment: Well, \newcounter{theorem} resolved the error, but I got "Theorem 1" "Theorem 2" "Theorem 3" in my output.

Comment: I am unable to duplicate your problem, even when I use [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) or [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm). Did you copy/paste my minimal example as-is and it gave you these errors? If so, are you able to include an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) in your original question that shows your code? Otherwise it would be very difficult to assess the problems without proper reproduction.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help you …

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
% save current section numbering
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\edef\tmpsect{\@currentlabel}}
% reset theorem counter with all headings
\@addtoreset{theorem}{chapter}
\@addtoreset{theorem}{section}
\@addtoreset{theorem}{subsection}
% add current section numbering to theorem number
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\tmpsect-\arabic{theorem}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{theorem}
Text
\end{theorem}
\section{Section}
\begin{theorem}
Text
\end{theorem}
\section{Section}
\begin{theorem}
Text
\end{theorem}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{theorem}
Text
\end{theorem}
\section{Section}
\begin{theorem}
Text
\end{theorem}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{theorem}
Text
\end{theorem}
\section{Section}
\begin{theorem}
Text
\end{theorem}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\begin{theorem}
Text
\end{theorem}
\section{Section}
\begin{theorem}
Text
\end{theorem}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{theorem}
Text
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

If not try to provide a minimal working example and clarify your question, please.

**Note**
that `\@currentlabel` represents the current label (wow …) which can be another then the current section. But as egreg said if you don’t use labels outside of groups (like `{figure}`) there should be no problems …

Comment: `\@currentlabel` may not reflect the current sectioning level: no `\label` outside a group should occur to make  this work.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks! I added this as note :-)